# Where is the definition of os.system() function?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm in learning mode---- this is probably a dumb question but here it is:
I know there is a system() function in os.py in python, but I can't find it in os.py in github.

According to python docs, it says that 'This is implemented by calling the Standard C function `system()`, and has the same limitations.'.So my question is "What is the mechanism behind this?"

code : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/os.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is written in C.

This code here (from `cpython/Modules/posixmodule.c`) is where `os.system` is defined.

```c
#ifdef HAVE_SYSTEM
#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
/*[clinic input]
os.system -> long

    command: Py_UNICODE

Execute the command in a subshell.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static long
os_system_impl(PyObject *module, const Py_UNICODE *command)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=5b7c3599c068ca42 input=303f5ce97df606b0]*/
{
    long result;

    if (PySys_Audit("os.system", "(u)", command) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    _Py_BEGIN_SUPPRESS_IPH
    result = _wsystem(command);
    _Py_END_SUPPRESS_IPH
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    return result;
}
#else /* MS_WINDOWS */
/*[clinic input]
os.system -> long

    command: FSConverter

Execute the command in a subshell.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static long
os_system_impl(PyObject *module, PyObject *command)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=290fc437dd4f33a0 input=86a58554ba6094af]*/
{
    long result;
    const char *bytes = PyBytes_AsString(command);

    if (PySys_Audit("os.system", "(O)", command) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    result = system(bytes);
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    return result;
}
#endif
#endif /* HAVE_SYSTEM */
```

Notice the line that calls `system(bytes)`. The `system` function in C is apart of the standard C library, so if you wish to learn more about the C function, you can look there.

You might be wondering, "Why is it written in C?". The answer is simple, C can easily interact with you computer, and although Python can too, another C module would be required to do this from Python. It's easier, better looking, and faster to write something like this directly in C.

Answer (score -1):

In os.py there is code to look for and import such system calls:

```
# Any new dependencies of the os module and/or changes in path separator
# requires updating importlib as well.
if 'posix' in _names:
    name = 'posix'
    linesep = '\n'
    from posix import *
    try:
        from posix import _exit
        __all__.append('_exit')
    except ImportError:
        pass
    import posixpath as path

    try:
        from posix import _have_functions
    except ImportError:
        pass

    import posix
    __all__.extend(_get_exports_list(posix))
    del posix
```

This may be what you were looking for in `os.py` -- at least as far as answer the question *why don't I see this in os.py?*

###### [posix](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Doc/library/posix.rst#modposix-----the-most-common-posix-system-calls) - The most common POSIX system calls

> This module provides access to operating system functionality that is
> standardized by the C Standard and the POSIX standard (a thinly
> disguised Unix interface).